# Correct way to serialize xml element that contains a list of other element in vb.net/c#

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, serialization

I want to generate a `XML` serializing two `vb.net classes` I want to write **babysitters contact info** and **payments received** (the payments are in a list and can be cash,ticket,check) something like:

```
<roor>
    <babysitters>
         <babysitter>
             <ID>1</ID>
             <Name>Diana Swal</Name>
             <Experience>3</Experience>
             <PaymentInfo>
                <bank>BBVA<bank>
                <account>1234567898<account>
             </PaymentInfo>
             <Payment id=1 type="cash" date="2015-06-06">
                 <description>a descr </description>                   
             </Payment>
             <Payment id=2 type="cash" date="2015-07-16">
                 <description>a descr </description>                   
             </Payment>
             <Payment id=3 type="cash" date="2015-07-16">
                 <description>a descr </description>                   
             </Payment>
         </babysitter>
         <babysitter>
             <ID>2</ID>
             <Name>Koryna Tokya</Name>
             <Experience>1</Experience>
             <PaymentInfo>
                <bank>New York<bank>
                <account>123477898<account>
             </PaymentInfo>
             <Payment id=11 type="check" date="2015-01-06">
                 <description>a descr </description>                   
             </Payment>
             <Payment id=22 type="check" date="2015-02-16">
                 <description>a descr </description>                   
             </Payment>
             <Payment id=33 type="cash" date="2015-03-16">
                 <description>a descr </description>                   
             </Payment>
         </babysitter>

    </babysitters>
</roor>
```

To do so I am trying:

```
<XmlRoot ("roor")> _
Public Class roor
        Public Property Babysitters As List(Of Babysitter)

        Public Sub New()
            Babysitters = New List(Of Babysitter)()
        End Sub
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Babysitter
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Experience As Integer
    'how to define payment info properties ?
    ' I guess an extra class is not necesary so instead of
    'defining each one of payment info maybe one property or struct
    'Public Property PaymentInfo As ????
    Public Property PaymentInfo_bank As String
    Public Property PaymentInfo_account As String

    'for the payments I am using an array of payments
    <XmlArrayItem("Payments")>
    Public Property Payments As List(Of Payment)

    Public Sub New()
        Payments = New List(Of Payment)()
    End Sub
End Class


<Serializable()>
    Public Class Payment
        <XmlAttribute("id")>
        Public Property id As Integer
        <XmlAttribute("type")>
        Public Property type As String
        <XmlAttribute("date")>
        Public Property date As String
        Public Property description As String
    End Class
```

How to serialize the info in a xml? Would that code definition generate a xml like the given one?

Answer (score 2):

If you've got an example xml file then you can generate the classes automatically from that to avoid any chance of differences.

1. Use the example xml file to generate an xsd (schema definition) - for instance in Visual Studio (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255829.aspx).
2. Use the xsd file to create your classes (in vb.net or c#) using xsd.exe - comes built into Visual Studio (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)